# swipe in uitableveiw ,Delete button does not appear. Also when I swipe it very fast, delete button appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe

I am trying to implement swipe to delete in `UITableView`. `ViewController` does not contain pan gesture or any other function. The `viewController` which contains `UITableView`, is pushed when side menu is selected. Following is the code I used.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableViewRefresh.dataSource = self;
    self.tableViewRefresh.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 1.0f;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

When I swipe, Delete button does not appear. But, when I swipe it very fast, delete button appears. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your support.

The issue has been fixed.

I have been using LGMenuController class for implementing navigation drawer on App. The class uses gesture recognition functionality through out the app for show/close the side menu by the swipe gesture.

It seems that the default feature of table view's swipe delete is overridden by gesture recogniser used in LGMenuController class. Once the gesture recognition has disabled completely,then the swipe delete functionality of UITableView works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue and fixed by disabling panMode of side menu. If you are using MFSideMenu have a look at bellow code-

```
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController:centerViewController
                                                    leftMenuViewController:leftViewController
                                                    rightMenuViewController:nil];

container.panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the default feature of tableview swipe delete is overridden by gesture recogniser used in same class or parent classes.Please check current class, parent class or libraries used in those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.  You can add n number of buttons as you want while swiping the uitableviewcell. Make sure you have return all the buttons in return statement `(return @[deleteAction, someOtherButtonName])`

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   

    // Delete button

    UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDestructive title:@"Delete"  handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){

        // Action for delete button

    }];

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return @[deleteAction];

}
```